# Wordpress Contact Form 7: populate the value of a field dynamically with PHP

Tags: contact, plugin-contact-form-7

Well my question is quite simple, I would like to populate a field with the value of a variable that have been passed via a $_GET Request.

thanks

Comment: I do it using `wpcf7_add_shortcode()` function [http://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/](http://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/)

Comment: You can execute any php-code and pass any variable there, incl. GET, POST, WP vars and functions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to extend the contact form. I don't know how this works nowadays and how the plugin has changed, but I had to do it in the past and I wrote a blog post about it: http://kovshenin.com/archives/wordpress-extending-the-contact-form-7-plugin/