# How to retrive Custom Fields as Values for a Form field

Tags: custom-field

I am constructing a theme for Wordpress that uses PAGES for products for sale on a site. This Product will have properties like DESCRIPTION, PRICE that will be stored to custom fields.

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the values from the custom fields and forward them to a form which is stored in another wordpress page. This form is a request for quotation form that the user fills out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When generating the form all you need is the post id of the product pages and you can use [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function to retive the information about that product , so basically you just need to pass the product post id. eg:

```
$price = get_post_meta($product_post_id,'price',true);
```

Comment: Is it possible to that with Contact Form 7? Passing the $price variable to the form?

Comment: read your reply here. I think that again answers my question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/wordpress-contact-form-7-populate-the-value-of-a-field-dynamically-with-php